# Are TURN Stats (send/receive and pacekts/bytes) only measurements between the Client and the Server?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I've been looking into the metrics emitted by `rfc5766-turn-server` and seem to be little confused as to the nature of:

```
  u32bits received_packets;
  u32bits sent_packets;
  u32bits received_bytes;
  u32bits sent_bytes;
  u64bits t_received_packets;
  u64bits t_sent_packets;
  u64bits t_received_bytes;
  u64bits t_sent_bytes;
```

---

**Question One**

Is my understanding here correct:

1. `received_packets` packets received by the TURN server from the client
2. `received_bytes` bytes received by the TURN server from the client
3. `sent_packets` packets sent to the client by the TURN server
4. `sent_bytes` bytes sent to the client by the TURN server

---

**Question 2**

What is the difference between `t_` metrics and those without the prefix? It looks like they're both totals.

---

**Question 3**

In a communcation flow where only peers send UDP packets to through the relayed transport address down to 'clients' such as:

```
    (allocated by Peer_A)
           TURN_A <-------------- Peer_B
         /              UDP      /
        /                       /
       /       UDP             /
  peer_A --------------> TURN_B  
                  (allocated by Peer_B)
```

In this single direction flow, peers only ever talk to clients through the Relayed Transport Address. If my assumptions above are correct, we will only get stats on `sent_packets` and `sent_bytes` as the data is always flowing toward the client (i.e. receive should be 0).

However in the logs, there is indeed `receive_` metrics (adding to my confusion).

---

It was mentioned here (https://github.com/coturn/coturn/issues/224), but its still a bit confusing.

---

turnutilts_uclient testing

**Sending traffic from the (client -> TURN -> no where)**

```
turnutils_uclient -v -s -c -n 35000 -m 2 -z 20 -l 160 -p 4172 -X -g -e 1.2.3.4 -u (username) -w (credential) (turn_ip)

results in

message=rcvp=2046, rcvb=425516, sentp=2, sentb=184
```

**Sending traffic from the (client -> TURN -> back to client) (-y option)**

```
turnutils_uclient -v -s -c -n 35000 -m 2 -z 20 -l 160 -p 4172 -X -g -y -u (username) -w (credential) (turn_ip)

results in 

message=rcvp=988, rcvb=205248, sentp=1060, sentb=253572
```

My tests seem to support that this metric is indeed, only the traffic flow between the client and the server.

`Sent packets/bytes` = packets/bytes sent to the client from the TURN server

`Receive packets/bytes` = packets/bytes received from the client on the TURN server

Now i'm even more confused as to how two ICE agents results in:

```
rcvp=1020, rcvb=907648, sentp=1028, sentb=919469
```

The `rcvb` and `rcvp` should be very low, since traffic should always be flowing from: `peer -> TURN -> client` for each call leg of a `relay-relay` candidate-paired call.

Comment: you might get more answers on the coturn mailing list

Comment: Ill do that, thanks Philipp. Its interesting - my confusion is stemming from the metrics I see in `rfc-5766-turn-server`. We use ICE, which I believe originally meant that traffic only ever flows from `peer -> relay transport address (TURN) -> client`. However, when looking at receive/sent metrics, I can see roughly the same size byte transfer in both directions.

Would you know if my assumption is correct, or will WebRTC/ICE ever result in a client sending traffic to a peer? I cant think of how this would happen given how ICE works.

Comment: Kris, are you sure the data is flowing how you describe it in Question 3? Is it possible instead that both A and B are exchanging bidirectional data over TURN, while the TURN servers are (or the single TURN server is) bridging the data over UDP between the relayed transport addresses? That would be easy to see with a network capture.

Comment: @giavac I will double check, but AFAIU, ICE will always result in multiple allocations with one-diretion traffic flow. If for example, the local and remote candidate are relay, each device will be talking to the relay transport address of the corresponding allocation. I cant think of how ICE would ever result in any other topology other than the one described in 3. This topology is a result of ICE negotiation and less about what the TURN server is capable of. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Added some testing at the tail end of my answer.